# Get R ANOVA Output to match Minitab

Tags: r, anova, minitab

I have fit a simple multiple linear regression model in R and printed the ANOVA output which looks like this:
[image: R output]

Is there a way to get the output to match the MINITAB ANOVA output:

[image: MINITAB output]

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your data?  The differences is most like related to how the data is structured and the underlying assumptions.

Comment: @Dave2e There are no differences in the regression fit. The Minitab table has collapsed the "contributions" of the two predictors into one row. Therefore it's less informative and the R summary is better.

Comment: @Dave2e that data I used here is exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

I did not find anything about the default type of the ANOVA used in MINITAB, but most likely it is type III. R's `anova` does type I ANOVA, however. When you have no "interaction terms", you can achieve a type III ANOVA in R with `drop1(..., test="F")`.

Explanation: type I ANOVA adds predictors one by one and tests the effect of their addition to the F statistic. Obviously, the result depends on the order in which the variables are added, i.e., `anova(lm(y~x1+x2, data))` leads to different p-values than `anova(lm(y~x2+x1, data))`. To avoid this problem, type III ANOVA tests the effect on the F statistic with just one variable omitted.

Each ANOVA variant has its issues. Type I ANOVA can assign "statistical significance" to a variable or not depending on the position in the formula. Type III ANOVA, OTOH, can identify all predictors as "statistically insignificant" even for a good predictive model, e.g. in cases of (multi-)collinear variables.